# Direction on a Sonar Effect?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm in pre development for a game that will hopefully have a sonar type effect. I.e. You cant see anything, then you send out a sonar ping and as the ping hits objects they becom illuminated. Does anyone have any ideas of where I would start. I'm using cocos2d so it's a sidescroller type game. Any help would really really help.

Comment: Look into basic cocos 2d development.  I could throw something like this together with a couple of sprites and collision detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping it simple, here is what I would do. Every update after the sonar is sent out, use `ccpDistance` and check if the distance between the start of the sonar and all of the objects you want to check is less than some variable `i` that gets incremented every update. In effect this is basically a growing circle that checks for objects inside its radius.

If the distance is less than `i`, run an action on the sprite, such as `[self runAction:[CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:5]]`. This will show the object then fade it out over a duration of 5. If you set the object to visible = false beforehand, you should get a nice sonar effect.

If you need the direction just get the vector from the sonar start position to the object when  it is visible.

Answer (score 0):

For illumination you could look at glColorMask - you can see it in action here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bj4ts5KRSTs&t=4m36s. In terms of collision detection, you would probably want to use Box2d.